# React Native: @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files

Tags: javascript, react-native, symlink

We've got two repos, both of which have `react-native` as dependencies; one being the actual RN app and the other a UI package with a number of custom react-native components in it.

When I symlink (using `npm link`) the UI package with the RN app and try start the js server, it throws the follow error:

`This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.`

It seems to be because it's picking up the same RN files inside the UI package's copy of `react-native`.

I know there's a problem with watchman not working with symlinks, however I think this is different - to do with there being two `react-native` modules. Does anyone know a way to get around this please? I've made sure that both are the same version number but still nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't RN be a peer dependency of your UI package?

Comment: Seems to have sorted that issue thanks @Nit. Although it can't seem to find the `index.ios.js` even though it's all there - but this must be a separate issue

Answer (score 13):

This has been destroying my day as well. as a quick workaround, you can just go delete the folder of react-native out of the node_modules folder within react-native-router-flux.(node_modules > react-native-router-flux > node_modules > **react-native**) Ugly, but will at least get you up and running for the time being

Comment: Happened for me too completely out of nowhere... but this will work for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have two of the same-named modules in your dependency tree, usually because you have two copies of a package with has a `@providesModule` declaration (typically `react-native`, it seems). A full example error:

```
This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: yargs
  Paths:
  /Users/me/Documents/git/MyProject/node_modules/react-native-macos/node_modules/yargs/package.json collides with:
  /Users/me/Documents/git/MyProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yargs/package.json
```

This is symptomatic of my working on a fork of React Native, `react-native-macos`, yet having installed `react-native` into the same repo.

In my case, I simply had to uninstall my self-installed `react-native` to proceed; in @Hafiz's case, his `react-native-router-flux` dependency was bundling its own copy of `react-native` internally, so he had to manually delete it – that fault is on the repo owners. Happily, they have resolved the [issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1803) since.